# Can windows installer default a program to use XP compatibility mode?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2008, windows-installer, windows-vista, c#-2.0

A client is having problems with an application we wrote but only when he runs it in Vista. It works fine however if he runs it in XP compatibility mode. While we get to the bottom of the Vista issue, is it possible to update our installer (Visual Studio 2008 windows forms installer for an app using .net 2.0) so that the installed program will automatically use compatibility mode? He does not want his users to have to update the settings manually.

Many thanks,

Adam.

Answer (score 2):

A related [winamp forum post](http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?threadid=260715) (*Vista: Making installed app run in XP compatibility mode*) suggests to set the following registry key:

```
HKCU "Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers" "[full application path goes here]" "WINXPSP2"
```

I haven't verified this, but I assume that the use of XP compatibility mode is a setting stored in the registry so I would suggest to use [**ProcMon**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to see what keys are changed when you apply the setting manually.

Finally make your installer add the correct key. It goes without saying, however, that in the long run you should fix the underlying problem.